# cmake-3.5.2 already installed, it's just not linked

Tags: ios, objective-c, homebrew, linphone

brew install cmake

Warning: cmake-3.5.2 already installed, it's just not linked

I am tring to install cmake but it shows above error.
Any suggestion helpful a lot....

Comment: have you tried `brew link cmake`?

Answer (score 2):

I run this command

```
brew link cmake
```

I got this error

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.5.2... 
>   Error: Could not symlink share/emacs/site-lisp/cmake
>   /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp is not writable.

After that i will gave full permissions to this folder (By sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp)

Again I run

```
brew link cmake
```

It's linked and every thing working fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. run `brew link cmake`
2. if that doesn't help then run `brew doctor` to figure out why it can't link it -- likely it is missing user rights to write to the folder.

Comment: Another reason for which it might not be able to link is that the link target(s) already exist. In that case you can run `brew link --overwrite cmake`.